# Rails Parent app route to engine route and children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ckeditor

In my Rails App I have an engine mounted which has a route for the [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor). For the ckeditor to work it needs the `/ckeditor` route path.

Currently my app's routes have the engine mounted at `/portfolio` such that the route to `ckeditor` is `/portfolio/ckeditor`. This doesn't work because ckeditor is looking for the route `/ckeditor` and sub routes, like `/ckeditor/pictures/...` which is fine.

How do I get my  app to map `/ckeditor` as an alias to `/portfolio/ckeditor` or how do I get the engine to mount ckeditor directly to `/ckeditor`?

Here are my routes files:

app route file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'front_page#index'
  get 'front_page/index'
  match '/about', to: 'front_page#about', via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'front_page#contact', via: 'get'
  mount BasicProjects::Engine => '/portfolio'

  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

end
```

Engine Route file

```
BasicProjects::Engine.routes.draw do
  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
  resources :projects
  resources :categories
  root 'projects#index'
end
```

Alternatively, is there a way in the `ckeditor` initializer to set the route path for ckeditor to `/portfolio/ckeditor` instead of `/ckeditor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the default CKEditor routes create a [config.js](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js) file within the host application.

```
# in app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  /* Filebrowser routes */
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/some_path/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/some_path/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/some_path/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/some_path/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/some_path/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/some_path/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/some_path/ckeditor/attachment_files";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure ckeditor so that it will build paths based on a custom URI. Per ckeditor's documentation, you can do so by setting a global javascript variable named `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH`:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Specifying_the_Editor_Path

The ckeditor gem also has an example in its documentation of how you might do this:

---

### Include customized CKEDITOR_BASEPATH setting

Add your app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/basepath.js.erb like

```
<%
  base_path = ''
  if ENV['PROJECT'] =~ /editor/i
    base_path << "/#{Rails.root.basename.to_s}/"
  end
  base_path << Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
  base_path << '/ckeditor/'
%>
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '<%= base_path %>';
```

---

Source: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#include-customized-ckeditor_basepath-setting

Comment: I added `/portfolio` to the base path resulting in `base_path = '/portfolio'` although that does not change how the routing works. What am I missing?